# BigQuery Tier 20 or higher required

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm attempting to run the following query within BigQuery:

```
SELECT 
    FORMAT_TIMESTAMP('%Y-%m-%d', TIMESTAMP_MICROS(date)) as target,
    SUM(CASE WHEN period = 7  THEN users END) as days_07,
    SUM(CASE WHEN period = 14 THEN users END) as days_14,
    SUM(CASE WHEN period = 30 THEN users END) as days_30
FROM (
    SELECT 
        activity.date as date,
        periods.period as period,
        COUNT(DISTINCT user) as users
    FROM (
        SELECT
            event.timestamp_micros as date, 
            user_dim.app_info.app_instance_id as user
        FROM `table.*` 
        CROSS JOIN 
            UNNEST(event_dim) as event  
    ) as activity
    CROSS JOIN (
        SELECT 
            event.timestamp_micros  as date
        FROM `table.*` 
        CROSS JOIN 
            UNNEST(event_dim) as event 
        GROUP BY event.timestamp_micros
    ) as dates
    CROSS JOIN (
        SELECT period 
        FROM 
            (
                SELECT 7 as period 
                UNION ALL 
                SELECT 14 as period 
                UNION ALL
                SELECT 30 as period
            )
    ) as periods
    WHERE 
        dates.date >= activity.date 
    AND 
        SAFE_CAST(FLOOR(TIMESTAMP_DIFF(TIMESTAMP_MICROS(dates.date), TIMESTAMP_MICROS(activity.date), DAY)/periods.period) AS INT64) = 0
    GROUP BY 1,2
)
GROUP BY date
ORDER BY date DESC
```

It is working and will select the active users for specific time frames if I run it on a single table but within my actual application I'm going to be running this on all my datasets (40+). When I attempt to run it on a single dataset with all tables `dataset.*` I get this error:

> Query exceeded resource limits for tier 1. Tier 20 or higher required.

I'm unsure what I can do now. I'm thinking that possibly I might have to end up moving this to code instead of SQL for performance sake.

Comment: Does it run with Tier 20 or higher? You can add in options. Add some info about the processing GB + time + explanation section after your run the query.

Comment: Where are the options for this? I've looked all over in Cloud Platform console.

Comment: https://www.screencast.com/t/3Tf1WDtkY

Comment: @Pentium10 Okay, I see that now. What will the impact on my charges be? This is an account owned by my employer. The query will only process 780k of data.

Comment: it's hard to tell, but your query is computing a lot of resources, anyway my next recommendation would be to run the query on smaller sets of data, it will be faster as it will run in parallel like table 1-10, then 11-20.

Comment: @Pentium10 Hmm, I don't think I really have the option to run it on smaller datasets, I'm already limiting it here. The actual query is going to be huge with many unions. Does BigQuery calculate charges based off data or how much resources are used? BigQuery gives me this message when trying to run it at Tier 1: `Valid: This query will process 761 KB when run. The cost will be around $0.00
`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I see the reason for this query to be CPU expensive so it gets "promoted" to that high billing tier

The reason is that sub-selects dates and activity have huge amount of rows because each row represents timestamp in microsecond so no pre-grouping is happenning at all

So, I recommend to transform below

```
FROM (
    SELECT
        event.timestamp_micros as date, 
        user_dim.app_info.app_instance_id as user
    FROM `table.*` 
    CROSS JOIN 
        UNNEST(event_dim) as event  
) as activity
```

into

```
    FROM (
      SELECT DISTINCT
          DATE(TIMESTAMP_MICROS(event.timestamp_micros))  AS DATE, 
          user_dim.app_info.app_instance_id AS user
      FROM `firebase-analytics-sample-data.android_dataset.app_events_20160607` 
      CROSS JOIN UNNEST(event_dim) AS event  
    ) AS activity
```

and respectively below

```
CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT 
        event.timestamp_micros  as date
    FROM `table.*` 
    CROSS JOIN 
        UNNEST(event_dim) as event 
    GROUP BY event.timestamp_micros
) as dates
```

into

```
    CROSS JOIN (
        SELECT DATE(TIMESTAMP_MICROS(event.timestamp_micros))  AS DATE
        FROM `firebase-analytics-sample-data.android_dataset.app_events_20160607`
        CROSS JOIN UNNEST(event_dim) AS event 
        GROUP BY 1
    ) AS dates
```

above change will make number of rows much more lower so than CROSS JOIN will be not that expensive

of course than you need respectively modify other pieces of your query to accommodate fact that now date fields are actually of DATE type and not microseconds anymore

Hope this helps!